# If current time is between x and y

Tags: jquery, datetime

I need to find the current time in day/hours/minute format, and then put it in an if statement depending on the time. I can get the current day and output, although a bit strange, I can get my head around it (I'm sure there are easier ways to do this). But when I run it in the if/else statement, the console.log text does not get any output.

What am I doing wrong??

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4MNL5/

```
var d = new Date();
var current_time = "" + d.getDay() + d.getHours() + d.getMinutes();

if (current_time >= 00000 && current_time =< 32359) {
    console.log("i'm between Sunday and Wednesday ");
}
else {
    console.log("i'm between Thursday and Sunday");
}
```

Comment: use `Date.parse` to get milliseconds from beginning.

Answer (score 5):

Your console should be showing a syntax error. There is no `=<` operator. It's spelled `<=`

Comment: Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/4MNL5/2/ ? This still gives no console log output.

Comment: You reversed the `>=` too! There's no `=>` operator either! The operators are `<=` and `>=` - stop trying to make them mirror images of each other.